# Why did Cersei's allies not help her on her Walk of Atonement?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Cersei had to do the Walk of Atonement to get back to the Red Keep. She was surrounded by crowds of people who threw things at her, spat on her and generally made the whole experience more miserable.

Why did none of her allies help her? They could have kept the crowds back, or intervened to pick her up in a carriage half way, or got off a few carefully sniped arrows at Unella. Instead they did nothing, waiting for her to reach the Red Keep by herself.

Comment: Remember, Margaery was still a prisoner of Faith Militants. Most of the people in power who could intervene didn't want to risk Margaery, save for the King who had no experience with violence to take strong decisions.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 that's actually the best explanation so far. They had hostages, and a King who was paralyzed with indecision.

Comment: Margaery was not a hostage and executing her in retaliation goes against what the Faith Militant are trying to portray themselves as. If they execute the Queen in retaliation, things are just as likely to backfire on them as it would be for the Lannisters to intervene in Cersei's walk.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I doubt they would have executed her, just kept her locked up for even longer until Cersei was returned. That was my point really, it was a relatively weak position considering that Cersei was willing to sacrifice pretty much anyone who is not an immediate family member. In the end she murdered Margaery anyway.

Comment: @user But Cersei didn't have a say in it? My point is though that the Faith Militant wouldn't retaliate against Margaery as that goes against who and what they are. Any retaliation would be direct against Cersei and those that helped her. Margaery wasn't a hostage after all.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think you give the Faith Militant too much credit.

Comment: @user They are violent but remember they haven't seized complete control by the time of Cersei's walk, they wouldn't throw it all away for some retaliation that in the grand scheme of things would be worthless anyway.

Answer (score 14):

Two reasons really, they wouldn't have "won" the fight and it probably would have voided Cersei's atonement. Of course Cersei herself could have met with them before the walk to tell them not to intervene but as that's off screen and we don't know for sure, I'll ignore it for now.

The High Sparrow already hints that the many are the ones who will beat the few when united properly and in this case they are united properly by the Faith Militant. Had the Lannisters, Kingsguard or Gold Cloaks got involved it likely would sparked a riot and the few would have been overridden.

> **High Sparrow:** Have you ever served the field, Lady Olenna? Have you ever reaped the grain? Has anyone in House Tyrell? A lifetime of wealth and power has left you blind in one eye. You are the few. We are the many. And when the many stop fearing the few...
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 5 Episode 7, "The Gift"</sub>

In fact that is precisely what they believed would happen when they decided to stop Margaery from her Walk of Atonement. In this case Cersei and Olenna are fighting to intervene, Cersei couldn't intervene with her own walk and Olenna probably wanted it to happen to some extent.

> **Kevan:** If it doesn’t go as planned, the Sparrows have many friends in the city. We’ll have civil war. Many will die.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 6 Episode 4, "Book of the Stranger"</sub>

Comment: I'm having a hard time accepting that Cersei wouldn't have happily had a riot and sacrificed a few peasants/soldiers to save herself. When you think about the number of innocent people who had murdered and showed no concern for...

Comment: @user Cersei would ___not___ have a riot with her directly _in the middle of it_. That's a good way to get yourself killed especially when you're the one they'd be rioting against.

Answer (score 2):

Which allies you mean?

The Tyrells had already been her enemies. It was actually Olenna Tyrell who orchestrated Cersei's arrest, after receiving the 'gift' from Littlefinger - "handsome young boy" Lancel Lannister. After this he confessed everything about Cersei to High Sparrow and Cersei was arrested.

Freys are too far away and it seems very unlikely that they would help her in this regard.

Boltons already betrayed her by marrying Ramsay with Sansa, which Cersei had already learned from Littlefinger.

King Tommen refused to use power against Faith militant already.

Jaime is on a "diplomatic mission" in Dorne, to protect Myrcella.

Kevan Lannister, the Hand of the King, and also the head of the army at that time, is angry at Cersei, since it was her who gave Faith militant the power. He is against her power plays in the Small Council, he would like to see Tommen there instead. He has no interest to help her.

So Cersei has no friends or allies, maybe appart from Qyburn, but he himself has not enough power to do that.